# Can I use property for C++ variable?

Tags: ios, ios7, objective-c++, ios7.1

I am using Objective-C++. Can I create a property of C++ class type?

I tried but it reports must be inherited from `NSObject`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but it cannot be a strong or weak reference (if you need that, look up `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr`).

```
class C {};

@interface D

@property(nonatomic, assign) C p;

@end
```